# Found the synthetic property @enterAnimation. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application. Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, karma-jasmine

When running Karma to test my Angular4 application, I get this error  `Found the synthetic property @enterAnimation. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.` though I already imported the module in **app.module.ts**

```
        // animation module
        import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; 
    ...
@NgModule({
    imports: [...
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ...
      ],
```

and in my **component**:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {
      trigger,
      state,
      style,
      animate,
      transition
    } from '@angular/animations';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-about',
      animations: [
        trigger(
          'enterAnimation', [
            transition(':enter', [
              style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0 }),
              animate('500ms', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1 }))
            ]),
            transition(':leave', [
              style({ transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1 }),
              animate('500ms', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0 }))
            ])
          ]
        ),
        trigger(
          'enterAnimationVetically', [
            transition(':enter', [
              style({ transform: 'translateY(100%)', opacity: 0 }),
              animate('500ms', style({ transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1 }))
            ]),
            transition(':leave', [
              style({ transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1 }),
              animate('500ms', style({ transform: 'translateY(100%)', opacity: 0 }))
            ])]
        )
      ],
...
```

The application runs perfectly with `ng serve` yet, I got this error with karma.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I found the solution. I just needed to import in `app.component.spec.ts` the same import

```
 // animation module
        import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; 
    ...
@NgModule({
    imports: [...
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ...
      ],
```

Comment: i'm trying to solve this problem and this solution isnt working for me.  Where do I place the @NgModule code in the file? right after the imports?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.. have you tried this on angular 6 by chance?  i was hoping your fix would clear the error for me but it doesnt..

Comment: future readers you can also get this exact error when you forget to place `animations: [ <yourAnimationMethod()> ]` on your @Component (only if youre using `[@yourAnimationMethod]` on the HTML template)

Comment: @Stavm you are the boss!  The animation has to be registered with the meta data of the component which can be easy to overlook, especially when using external animation files. Angular could do with a specific error in this circumstance as it is the last place I was looking to find the answer.

Comment: @Stavm thanks, this solved my issue, you should add it as a different answer to be more visible for others with the same issue.

Comment: Thanks very helpful

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer. The right answer is below reported by bravotango

Comment: After importing `BrowserAnimationsModule` to `my-component.spec.ts` the error would still appear. I finally fixed it by importing `BrowserAnimationsModule` in every single test file of my other components as well. It seems that all components inside the same module need to have this import in their test files, even if they do not use animations themselves.

Comment: in my cause it said that browser module was already imported, so I got one level up in my app component and added there the browser animations module and it works.

Answer (score 146):

Future readers: you can also get this exact error, when you forget to place

```
animations: [ <yourAnimationMethod()> ]
```

on your `@Component` ts file.

that is if you're using `[@yourAnimationMethod]` on the HTML template, i.e. [angular animations](https://angular.io/guide/animations).

Comment: Exactly. This error is not necessarily surfaced because of failure to import `BrowserAnimationsModule`.

Comment: I had incorrectly imported the animation to the component being animated, I needed to import the animation on the component that holds the router outlet.  Thanks @stavm - it is a misleading error as I had already imported the Animations modules

Comment: you pick it exactly. Thanks @Stavm.

Comment: Thanks I had forgot animations while cloning a component... :)

Answer (score 28):

For my Angular 6 application, I resolved the issue by adding the following to my component *.spec.ts* file:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Then add the `BrowserAnimationsModule` to the imports of the `TestBed.configureTestingModule` in the same component *.spec.ts* file

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LinkedSitesComponent ], imports: [ BrowserAnimationsModule ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Comment: I was facing a similar kind of issue while running Karma test case. And this fixed my issue. However, it was strange that my component didn't import BrowserAnimationsModule, nor the same imported to its parent :)

Comment: Gave a thumb up, @bravo.

Answer (score 14):

For angular 7 and previous version, you only need to add this line in your `app.module.ts` file, and remember put it in the imports array modules too in the same file:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
```

Answer (score 12):

If you face this error in `Storybook`, then do import this `BrowserAnimationsModule` to `moduleMetadata` in your story.
Like this,

```js
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


export const Primary = () => ({
  template: `
   <div style="width: 720px">
    <view-list [data]="data"></view-list>
   </div>
   `,
  moduleMetadata: {
    imports: [AppModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
  },
  props: {
    data: SOME_DATA_CONSTANT,
  },
});
```

PS: For Angular, the answers that are mentioned above works well.

Answer (score 6):

If you see this error during unit testing then you could import utility module like `NoopAnimationsModule` into your spec file which mocks the real animation and donot actually animate

`import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`

Comment: This should be the top and accepted answer, adding BrowserAnimationsModule  actually worsens further by adding more failures to the test spec file.

For unit testing purpose, NoopAnimationsModule should be used.

Answer (score 4):

if included `BrowserAnimationsModule` but still not working, you will have to add `animations` attribute to your @component like this

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-orders',
  templateUrl: './orders.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./orders.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({
        height: '0px',
        minHeight: '0'
      })),
      state('expanded', style({
        height: '*'
      })),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-   bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 2):

for my case all i did was add this line to my component (users-component.ts)

```
@Component({
animations: [appModuleAnimation()],
})
```

of course ensure you have imported the relevant module in app.component.ts or where you import your modules

```
 // animation module
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; 

    @NgModule({
         imports: [
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ],
    })
```