# Angular App: "export 'AnimationBuilder' was not found in '@angular/animations'"

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have an Angular4 application (which was automatically generated by hyperledger composer).

I installed angular/animations using the following command:

```
npm install --save @angular/animations@4.0.0
```

I received the following warning:

```
@angular/animations@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

This warning warning made no sense because Angular/core@4.0.0 is installed (screenshot of package.json file):

[image]

Anyway ... When running the app, everything looks fine in the browser. But in the console, the following error message is displayed:

```
Error: Found the synthetic property @transitionMessages. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.
```

After importing the BrowserAnimationsModule, however, the whole app break down.

In the browser, the following error message is displayed:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730753/found-the-synthetic-property-enteranimation-please-include-either-browseranim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all

> This warning warning made no sense because Angular/core@4.0.0 is installed.

In your dependencies, you have `@angular/core: ^4.0.0`. Notice the caret (^) at the beginning. The caret [installs the most recent major version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/2227788). This is why you have an unmet dependency error: You probably have one of the latest 4+ versions of `@angular/core`, but on the other hand, you are explicitly installing the `4.0.0` version of `@angular/animations`. You can check which exact version of `@angular/core` you are actually using by going into `node_modules` and navigating to `@angular > core > package.json`.

As for your main question, I believe [AnimationBuilder](https://www.yearofmoo.com/2017/06/new-wave-of-animation-features.html) was added in Angular 4.2, so that's why you are probably having an issue, since you are installing `4.0.0`. Change the entry `@angular/animations: 4.0.0` in `package.json` to `@angular/animations: ^4.0.0` and then remove your `node_modules` and run `npm i` again.