# Angular 5 - ng test - Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule"

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular5, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

I have some browser animations in my application that are working fine with no errors.  When I run `ng test` i'm getting this error even though I'm including the `BrowserAnimationsModule` in my `app.module.ts` file.  I'm using animations within my `HeaderComponent`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeEs from '@angular/common/locales/es';

registerLocaleData(localeEs, 'es-us')

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730753/found-the-synthetic-property-enteranimation-please-include-either-browseranim) but still having the same issue..

Answer (score 13):

you just need to mock animation

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        NoopAnimationsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
});
```

---

If you are injecting the AnimationBuilder:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private builder: AnimationBuilder,
        ...
    ) { }
```

You'll need to provide it in your spec file like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        NoopAnimationsModule,
      ],
      declarations: ...,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ...,
          useClass: ...
        },
          NoopAnimationsModule,
        {
          provide: ...,
          useValue: ...,
        }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Comment: What worked for me was putting NoopAnimationsModule for both 'imports' and 'providers', as shown in last example.

Answer (score 2):

For me in Angular 12, I believe this should help in earlier versions too, I followed instructions from this github issues post: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15713

I have a test.ts file and I added the NoopAnimationsModule to the initTestEnvironment. On top of what the other posts suggested. It wasn't until I updated the test.ts file did the error go away

test.ts file

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  [BrowserDynamicTestingModule, NoopAnimationsModule],
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

only import the NoopAnimationsModule in the imports array of your spec file

```
imports: [...., NoopAnimationsModule],
```